# javascript innerHTML is not overridden

Tags: javascript

document.form1.field1.innerHTML="hi1"; works in onload() function.

but the same doesnt work if it is placed in some onclick() function/ some other function. If placed in onclick function, document.form1.field1.innerHTML="hi1"; is not overridden.

what we suppose to do in order to work?

Comment: Please provide an example of it not working.

Comment: you can create an example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Are you perhaps defining the `onclick` handler directly to an element before the dom is ready?

Answer (score 0):

1. in plain JS please use .value instead of .innerHTML for form fields
2. if you use an onclick handler of a link or a submit button you need to return false

Assuming

a) a form named form1
b) inline event handlers for sake of clarity (Purist can close their eyes for a second, ok?), this would work

`<a href="#" onclick="document.form1.field1.value='value from link'; return false">Set value from link</a>`

and so would this:

`<input type="button" onclick="document.form1.field1.value='value from button'" value="Set value from button" />`

`<input type="checkbox" id="chk1"
onclick="document.form1.field1.value=this.checked?this.value:''" value="value from button" /><label for="chk1">Set value from checkbox</label>`

No need for return false on a button or check/radiobox